# Actualización de la DB segun cambio de SwitchInptu kartik yii2

Tags: php, yii2

estoy trabajando en yii2, tengo una tabla ASISTENCIAS(Id_asistencias, mañana, tarde, observaciones), esta es para llevar el control de asistencias, 1= presente, 0= Ausente, en la columna MAÑANA quiero usar un SwitchInput de kartik, y que cuando se haga el cambio en el SwitchInput, quiero que se guarde los valores en la Base de Datos, soy nuevo en esto, y no sé realmente como implementarlo para obtener los resultados que busco, estaré muy agradecido por sus respuestas.

hasta el momento esto es lo que logré y este es mi código index.php

```
    <?php
  $gridColumns = [

    [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
        'contentOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'width'=>'36px',
        'header'=>'',
        'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style']
    ],
    
    [

        'attribute' => 'Id_contribuyente',
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign' => 'leftArrow',
         // Mostrar el nombre de la persona
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
        'value' => 'contribuyente.persona.nombresapellidos',
        'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Contribuyentes::find()->joinWith('persona')->all(), 'Id_contribuyente', 'persona.nombresapellidos'),
        'filterWidgetOptions' => [
            'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select...')
            ],
        ],

    ],

    [
        'attribute' => 'Id_reuniones', 
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
        'value'=>function($model){
            $reunion = Reuniones::findOne($model->Id_reuniones);
                return $reunion->referencia;
            },
            'filter'=>  ArrayHelper::map(Reuniones::find()->all(), 'Id_reuniones', 'referencia'),
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
            'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select...')
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'mañana',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return SwitchInput::widget([
                'name' => 'mañana',
                'value' => $model->mañana,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'onText' => 'Presente',
                    'offText' => 'Ausente',
                    // Otras opciones que desees configurar
                ],
            ]);
        },
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=> 'tarde',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'hAlign' => 'center'
    ],
    
    [
        //'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'observaciones', 
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'hAlign' => 'center'
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        //'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
        'urlCreator' => function ($action, Asistencias $model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return Url::toRoute([$action, 'Id_asistencias' => $model->Id_asistencias]);
        }
    ],
];
?>

<?= GridView::widget([ 
    
'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
//'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div align='center'>{pager}</div>",
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'pjax' => true,
'responsive'=>true,
'hover'=>true,
'toolbar'=>[
    '{export}',
    '{toggleData}'
],
'panel' =>[
    'heading'=>Yii::t('app', 'Control de asistencia de Contribuyentes'),
    'type'=>'info',
   // 'before'=>Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create User'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
   // 'after'=>Html::a('<i class="fas fa-redo"></i> Reset Grid', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
    ],
]);
?>
```

[image: SwitchInput]